# What is the nature of motion formed by the superposition of two SHMs in the frequency ratio $1:\sqrt{2}$

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

When two simple harmonic motions (SHM) with frequencies in the ratio of two integers are superposed, the resulting motion is periodic. However, if SHMs with frequency ratio $1:\sqrt{2}$ are superposed, the resultant motion will not be periodic. Is this true? Why is this so? Does anyone have some intuition about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motion is periodic when one oscillator completes $n$ cycles while the second completes $m$ cycles, with both $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, or alternatively when the first oscillator completes one cycle the second completes $m/n$ cycles, where $m/n$ is rational.

$\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number so while one oscillator completes *one* cycle, the other canot complete a rational number of cycles.

Comment: Thanks, @ZerpTheHero Just for some intuition: can we say that if $\sqrt{2}$ is approximated by $1.414213$ instead of $1.414$, the time period of the periodic motion increases, and since $\sqrt{2}$ is a non-terminating decimal. the time period effectively goes to infinity making the motion nonperiodic.

Comment: yes.  In your case it would return to a position very close to (but not exactly) its initial position after 1414 cycles, closer still after 1414213 cycles etc.

Comment: Is this the same as the **quasiperiodic** motion?

Comment: if we go by [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperiodic_motion) it seems so yes.